# What is the damaged area in Drawing View Group in Android

Tags: android, canvas, view

I am going through the developer console and read this regarding [Drawing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

> Drawing is handled by walking the tree and recording the drawing
>   commands of any View that needs to update. After this, the drawing
>   commands of the entire tree are issued to screen, clipped to the newly
>   damaged area.

I didn't quite understand about the term "the newly damaged area".
Can someone elaborate it?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

damaged area here means invalidated area, where pixels need be updated.